# Error when inserting row to SQLite database - iOS (I think its something to do with data types)

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, sqldatatypes

In my code I am trying to insert a new row to a table in a SQLite database I create.
Now when I create open the database, I check to see if it is opened properly and it is, but when I try inserting a row into one of the tables, It doesn't work. Part of the code checks to see if a DB file already exists in the documents folder, and creates one if not. Now I think there might be a problem with datatypes... Would that create an error? Here is the code, notice that the values inserted into the tables are properties of an object defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) int connectionRefNumber;
@property (nonatomic) int otherUserID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * otherUserName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * otherUserProfilePicturePath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * connectionDate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL * otherUserFB;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL * otherUserTW;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL * otherUserHP;
```

The database method that opens the database and populates the tables (database itself is created, if doesn't exists, in another method). This is part of a special class I have created to handle all database related tasks:

```
-(void)initDatabase {
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
/*NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"];*/
NSArray * pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * databasePath = [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"];

BOOL databaseAlreadyExists = /*[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];*/NO;


if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"DATABASE OPEN");
    if (!databaseAlreadyExists){
        const char * sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONNECTIONS (CONNECTIONREFNUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT , OTHERUSERID INTEGER, OTHERUSERNAME VARCHAR, OTHERUSERPICTUREPATH VARCHAR, CONNECTIONDATE DATETIME, OTHERUSERFB BOOL, OTHERUSERTW BOOL, OTHERUSERHP BOOL)";
        char *error;
        if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"DATABSE AND TABLES CREATED");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ErrorL %s", error);
        }
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"cant open database");
}
```

}

Lastly, code I use to call this method, **HERE IS PROBABLY WHAT I DO WRONG IN TERMS OF DATA TYPES**:

```
ConectionsDataController * dataController = [[ConectionsDataController alloc] init];
//[dataController initDatabase];
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
int ID = 1;
int RefNumber = 1;
BOOL fb = YES;
BOOL tw = YES;
BOOL hp = YES;
NSDate *connectionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1955-02-24"];
connectionData * connectionObject = [[connectionData alloc]initWithConnectionRefNumber:&RefNumber    otherUserID:&ID otherUserName:@"John Jones" otherUserProfilePicturePath:@"/1" connectionDate:connectionDate otherUserFB:&fb otherUserTW:&tw otherUserHP:&hp];
[dataController insertConnectionToDatabase:connectionObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had someone else look at my code and he unveiled the problem, so i decided to share it here:

In the database, I have one of the columns defined as a PRIMARY KEY. this mean that it has to be unique for every row. Now for testing purposes, i just used one, so it worked once, but when i tried it again (still with 1), it wasn't unique therefore it couldn't be placed as the value of the primary key column.

Just something to look at when developing and debugging, as it may get overlooked, especially with not much experience at working with databases.